# Call to member function error - please help!

Tags: admin, customer, fatal-error, password, store-id

I am trying to fix an error with an extension.  The error appears when you are in admin and changing a customer's password.  The new password does get saved in the database, but the page throws this error:

> Call to a member function getStoreId() on a non-object in
>   /home/demo/public_html/naagtag/app/code/local/FME/Invoice/Model/Order/Pdf/Order.php

Here is the code on that phtml:

```
class FME_Invoice_Model_Order_Pdf_Order extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice
{

    public function getPdf ($orders = array())
    {
       // print_r($orders);exit;
        $this->_beforeGetPdf();
        $this->_initRenderer('invoice');

        $pdf = new Zend_Pdf();
        $this->_setPdf($pdf);
        $style = new Zend_Pdf_Style();
        $this->_setFontBold($style, 10);

        foreach ($orders as $order) {
            if ($order->getStoreId()) {
                Mage::app()->getLocale()->emulate($order->getStoreId());
                Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($order->getStoreId());
            }
            $page = $pdf->newPage(Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);
            $pdf->pages[] = $page;

            /* Add image */
            $this->insertLogo($page, $order->getStore());

            /* Add address */
            $this->insertAddress($page, $order->getStore());

            /* Add head */
            $this->insertOrder($page, $order, Mage::getStoreConfigFlag(self::XML_PATH_SALES_PDF_INVOICE_PUT_ORDER_ID, $order->getStoreId()));


            $page->setFillColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(1));
            $this->_setFontRegular($page);
           // $page->drawText(Mage::helper('sales')->__('Order # ') . $order->getIncrementId(), 35, 780, 'UTF-8');

            /* Add table */
            $page->setFillColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_RGB(0.93, 0.92, 0.92));
            $page->setLineColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0.5));
            $page->setLineWidth(0.5);

            $page->drawRectangle(25, $this->y, 570, $this->y -15);
            $this->y -=10;

            /* Add table head */
            $page->setFillColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_RGB(0.4, 0.4, 0.4));
            $page->drawText(Mage::helper('sales')->__('Products'), 35, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
            $page->drawText(Mage::helper('sales')->__('SKU'), 255, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
            $page->drawText(Mage::helper('sales')->__('Price'), 380, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
            $page->drawText(Mage::helper('sales')->__('Qty'), 430, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
            $page->drawText(Mage::helper('sales')->__('Tax'), 480, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
            $page->drawText(Mage::helper('sales')->__('Subtotal'), 535, $this->y, 'UTF-8');

            $this->y -=15;

            $page->setFillColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));

            /* Add body */
            foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
                if ($item->getParentItem()) {
                    continue;
                }

                if ($this->y < 15) {
                    $page = $this->newPage(array('table_header' => true));
                }

                /* Draw item */
                //temporarily set item as if we were printing an invoice
                $item->setQty($item->getQtyOrdered());
                $item->setOrderItem($item);
                $page = $this->_drawItem($item, $page, $order);
            }

            /* Add totals */
            $order->setOrder($order);
            $page = $this->insertTotals($page, $order);

            if ($order->getStoreId()) {
                Mage::app()->getLocale()->revert();
            }
        }

        $this->_afterGetPdf();

        return $pdf;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It means that one (or more) of your values in the `$orders` array is not an instance of an object (the expected type is likely `Mage_Sales_Model_Order`), but is a primitive type, like a boolean, string, or integer.

I'd check to see what those values are, and where they are coming from. That should provide you some more clarity on how to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for answering tjons!!!

i did what you recommended and got the following values when placed just above the line that throws the error:

var dump on $orders:
array(1) { [0]=> NULL }

print_r on $orders:
Array ( [0] => )

not really sure what to do with that info though